# Chrome, Firefox, Chromium all freezing and crashing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome, chromium, freeze

Chrome, Firefox, and Chromium all have the same issue: sometimes a tab will lock up and need to be closed. Sometimes it shows an "Aw, snap" error SIGSEGV. Sometimes it totally freezes Ubuntu requiring a computer power reset. It usually happens when I interact with a webpage, no matter the website.

I just switched over my PC from Windows 10 Home 64bit to Ubuntu 20.04 and have been having this problem since. Everything worked fine in Windows, so there doesn't seem to be any hardware issue. Memory and CPU usage are low as expected only using a single Chrome tab. Regardless, some basic specs:

- Ryzen 5 3600
- RTX 2060
- 16 GB memory

I tried switching from open-source to NVIDIA proprietary drivers and am still having the same issue.

I tried disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome and it didn't change anything.

This is the terminal output when running `google-chrome`:

```
[8497:8497:0211/175822.461775:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[8452:8493:0211/175824.552269:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[8452:8493:0211/175824.552290:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[8500:4:0211/175829.110495:ERROR:node_controller.cc(585)] Trying to re-add dropped peer 40668D003E7A5694.249DC4A06975B5FA
[8914:8917:0211/175932.729937:ERROR:node_controller.cc(585)] Trying to re-add dropped peer 38F48EECFFF76CEA.61DF7F1E8E26DAD1
[8500:4:0211/175932.730093:ERROR:node_controller.cc(585)] Trying to re-add dropped peer 38F48EECFFF76CEA.61DF7F1E8E26DAD1
```

The final two messages were paired with an "Aw, snap!" Error code: SIGSEGV screen

**EDIT**

I've also tried to no avail:

- `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome`
- clearing the cache
- using incognito mode
- using different memory sticks from a different brand

Comment: Download memtest86 from https://www.memtest86.com/ and check RAM of the computer using live media. Then reports results. It should not have errors.

Comment: @N0rbert I did two memtest passes and there were no errors

Comment: In the browser settings, disable Hardware Acceleration. Then, be sure to restart the browser.

Comment: @KGIII Yep I did that, see the notes on things I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been a faulty CPU, after replacing with a Ryzen 7 3800 the problem is resolved.

Answer (score -2):

delete all those browsers and try:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install snapd && sudo snap install brave
```

I hope it gonna work

and also those aren't some basic specs lol-

*-By NacreousDawn596, answering questions just for fun.*

Comment: Brave has the same issue as the other Chromium-based browsers and Firefox ESR randomly crashes. Even if they had worked I'm not really looking to switch browsers.

Comment: It should be noted that `firefox-esr` package does not exist in the official Ubuntu repositories. It is available from [`ppa:mozillateam/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=focal) .